# Failing to upload image stream to S3 because origin image has no content-length header

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

Does anyone know how to get around the problem of uploading a remote image to S3 when no content-length headers are returned by it?

I ran into this bug:

This url was causing my app to crash:

http://image.slidesharecdn.com/socialidentitytheory-100520110655-phpapp02/95/social-identity-theory-1-728.jpg

I traced it to the absence of content-length headers, which screws up this section of my code:

```
http.get(url, function (res) {
        if (parseInt(res.headers['content-length'], 10) > nconf.get('max_token_image_size')) {
            callback({error_code: 1, error_name: 'File too large'}, res);
        } else {
            var headers = {
                'Content-Length': res.headers['content-length'], 'Content-Type': res.headers['content-type'], 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=600'
            };
            s3.putStream('/token_photos/' + token_uuid + extension, res, 'public-read', headers, function (err, res) {
                logger.log('debug', 'res', res);
                logger.log('debug', 'putting photo to S3 ' + url);
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                callback(err, res);

            });
        }

    });
```

The headers look like this http://screencast.com/t/Tlewln6llGVN

Comment: Can you use the size of the response body?

Comment: Have you tried using something like [s3-upload-stream](https://github.com/nathanpeck/s3-upload-stream) to upload a file to S3 instead?

Comment: I think the problem multipart is the min 5MB part size, whereas my files are in the 300K range.

Comment: @Musa I think the problem with response.body is that this is streaming. I could detect the missing content length header in this case, and temporarily save to disk, but that is pretty undesirable in my environment.

Comment: Since you getting a chunked response, couldn't you send the file that same way using transfer encoding chunked.